# Unable to update phone number using elastic search query, getting mapper_parsing_exception

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to update the phone number using the below query, but I am getting "mapper_parsing_exception. Refer the code attached below.

**Query:**

```
POST /ps/_update/alOKenkBHofR-Ip1hPcv
{
  "doc": {
    "ph": {
      "na": null,
      "nu": "877842376",
      "cc": "91",
      "ex": null,
      "pt": "M"
    },
    "mdt": "20210615T044700.714Z"
  }
```

**Response:**

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "failed to parse field [ph] of type [text] in document with id 'alOKenkBHofR-Ip1hPcv'. Preview of field's value: '{cc=91, na=null, ex=null, pt=M, nu=877842376}'"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "failed to parse field [ph] of type [text] in document with id 'alOKenkBHofR-Ip1hPcv'. Preview of field's value: '{cc=91, na=null, ex=null, pt=M, nu=877842376}'",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "illegal_state_exception",
      "reason" : "Can't get text on a START_OBJECT at 1:3558"
    }
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

// code

```
 Document document = Document.create();
            Map<String, Object> map = new Phone.ToMap().convert((Phone) value);
            document.put(key, map);

        UpdateQuery updateQuery = UpdateQuery.builder(id).withDocument(document).build();
        UpdateResponse updateResponse = operations.update(updateQuery, indexCoordinates());
        Result result = updateResponse.getResult();
```

Comment: Can you share your mapping please? The error indicating that your ph data type is string but you are trying to pass a nested object.

Comment: "ph" : {
              "properties" : {
                "cc" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "fields" : {
                    "keyword" : {
                      "type" : "keyword",
                      "ignore_above" : 256
                    }
                  }
                },
                "nu" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "fields" : {
                    "keyword" : {
                      "type" : "keyword",
                      "ignore_above" : 256
                    }
                  }

Comment: @Kaveh Added mapping for ph above

Comment: Are you sure document you are trying to update is _doc type? As I don't know which version of ES are you using. Also could you please share the data you are trying to update "alOKenkBHofR-Ip1hPcv"?

Comment: @Kaveh 7.12.0 is version

Comment: @Kaveh "id": "alOKenkBHofR-Ip1hPcv", "cdt": "2021-05-17T13:36:07.019Z", "mdt": "2021-06-14T19:49:28.936Z", "pid": 145, "bi": { ,"ph": { "cc": "91", "nu": "7299430319", "pt": "M", "pn": "91729560319" }}

Comment: As I can see your ph is part of bi so you will need to give exact path.

Comment: Is your problem solved @selvi?

Comment: @Kaveh We caught into another data-related issue, after that issue gets resolved only I can verify the above one, I will update soon

Comment: So please accept my answer and upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ph` is part of `bi` object so for updating your document you should do this query:

```
POST /ps/_update/alOKenkBHofR-Ip1hPcv
{
  "doc": {
    "bi"{
        "ph": {
          "na": null,
          "nu": "877842376",
          "cc": "91",
          "ex": null,
          "pt": "M"
         }
    },
    "mdt": "20210615T044700.714Z"
  }
```